# How to unnest multiple columns while including nulls

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-normalization

I have a table that looks like:

| id | site_names | site_addresses | industries | feis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Borden Incorporated | 198 Saluda St , Chester , SC , 29706-1579 , United States|198 Saluda St, Chester, SC 29706, USA|198 Saluda St Chester SC 29706-1579 United States | Food and Cosmetics | 12345|45678 |
| 31 | Butterkrust Bakeries, Inc.|Flowers Baking Co. of Lakeland, LLC|Southern Bakeries, Inc. dba Butterkrust Bakeries | null | Food|Food and Cosmetics | 12345 |
| 33 | Church & Dwight Canada Corp. | 5485 RUE FERRIER , , MONTREAL, QUEBEC Quebec , , -- , CA | null | null |

I want to split the table into a materialized view where each row is one of the combinations possible when you split site_names, site_addresses, industries, and feis up. So for example, a few rows from this data would be:

| id | site_name | site_address | industry | fei |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Borden Incorporated | 198 Saluda St , Chester , SC | Food and Cosmetics | 12345 |
| 30 | Borden Incorporated | 198 Saluda St , Chester , SC | Food and Cosmetics | 45678 |
| 30 | Borden Incorporated | 198 Saluda St, Chester, SC 29706, USA | Food and Cosmetics | 12345 |
| 30 | Borden Incorporated | 198 Saluda St, Chester, SC 29706, USA | Food and Cosmetics | 45678 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 31 | Butterkrust Bakeries, Inc. | null | Food | 12345 |
| 31 | Flowers Baking Co. of Lakeland, LLC | null | Food | 12345 |

I have tried several ways to accomplish this. The closest I got was with this code:

```
(
with Expanded2 as (
    select raw_site_data.id as id_fei,
           feis.feis
    from raw_site_data,
         unnest(string_to_array(raw_site_data.feis, '|')) feis
),
     Expanded3 as (
         select raw_site_data.id as id_name,
                site_names.site_names
         from raw_site_data,
              unnest(string_to_array(raw_site_data.site_names, '|')) site_names
     )
     ,
     Expanded4 as (
         select raw_site_data.id as id_address,
                site_addresses.site_addresses
         from raw_site_data,
              unnest(string_to_array(raw_site_data.site_addresses, '|')) site_addresses)
     ,
     Expanded5 as (
         select raw_site_data.id as id_industry,
                industries.industries
         from raw_site_data,
              unnest(string_to_array(raw_site_data.industries, '|')) industries)
select id_fei as site_id, feis as fei, site_names as site_name, site_addresses as site_address, industries as industry
    from Expanded2, Expanded3, Expanded4, Expanded5 where Expanded2.id_fei = Expanded3.id_name and Expanded3.id_name = Expanded4.id_address and Expanded4.id_address = Expanded5.id_industry
    );
```

which is really close but it does not include any of the rows with nulls in it. Does anyone know how I can do this query while including rows with nulls in the result?

Couple more potentially relevant background points:

1. id is a unique, non-null integer in the original table
2. Site_names, site_addresses, industries, and feis all need to be split and all may have null values that I want included
3. I am using Postgres 13

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all combinations, you can use a single query:

```
select rd.id, site_name, site_address, fei
from raw_data rd left join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(rd.site_names, '\|') site_name
     on 1=1 left join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(rd.site_addresses, '\|') site_address
     on 1=1 left join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(rd.feis, '\|') fei
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: This worked almost perfectly, thank you! A quick note for people who stumble onto this in the future: You have to change the `'|'` regex to `'\|'` but then it works perfectly.